# Android not showing folder in `Android/data`

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, android

I've created an Android app that uses its own "external files directory".

This should be located on the device under `Android/data/<package_name>/<folder_name>`.

In my case `<package_name>` is `foo.bar` and `<folder_name>` is `baz`.

My device is set to transfer files and I can browse the files on my Windows computer. I navigated to `Android/data`:

[image: Image of file explorer in <code>Android/data</code> directory of device]

I can see loads of other apps such as `com.google.android.youtube`. However, I cannot find `foo.bar` anywhere.

What's funny is, I know that it's there: I thought at first that I had to manually create the folder if the app didn't put any files in it yet, so I created a new folder. If I give it the name "foo.bar", it jumps back to being named "New Folder".

[image]

But when I name it anything else such as "super.user" it shows up with that name.

[image]

So clearly "foo.bar" must already exist. I then tried to manually type in "foo.bar" in the address bar, and it doesn't exist!

[image]

This seems to be a problem with Windows File Explorer.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Rule #1 of tech support: Have you restarted explorer? the PC?

Comment: @DavidPostill  Haha, I restarted explorer, but I'll try restart the PC in a few minutes, just in the middle of something.

Comment: Are you showing all files? What user is the Android app using? This is likely a file permissions error

Comment: @DavidPostill I restarted my computer and it still wasn't showing. But after restarting my phone it is now showing :) Thanks for all your help

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a self-solved issue with a user-specific solution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is self solved and does not need more answers

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved: After restarting my phone, the files are now showing.